# PagedList doesn't make a real paging in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagedlist

In my project, I need to make a paging to a query. I use entity framework to get data from database. [This video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srN56uxw76s) explain how to make a paging to a query. Briefly, the video say all you have to do is to install PagedList.Mvc to your project and this code

```
.ToPagedList(PageNumber,PageSize)
```

For the first moment, it seems that this work and it is work for my, but I found that (after using Sql server profile to check what entity framework pass to sql server) entity framework ask sql server for all data and then select the needed data. To be more clear, this is my code on c# (server side)

```
var messages = db.Messages.Where(x => x.User1 == 1 && x.User2 == 2).OrderBy(x=>x.Date).ToList().ToPagedList(1,4);
```

And what is passed to sql server is this :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[User1] AS [User1], 
    [Project1].[User2] AS [User2], 
    [Project1].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
    [Project1].[TextContent] AS [TextContent], 
    [Project1].[ReadBit] AS [ReadBit], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[ReceivedBit] AS [ReceivedBit]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[User1] AS [User1], 
        [Extent1].[User2] AS [User2], 
        [Extent1].[Direction] AS [Direction], 
        [Extent1].[TextContent] AS [TextContent], 
        [Extent1].[ReadBit] AS [ReadBit], 
        [Extent1].[ReceivedBit] AS [ReceivedBit], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date]
        FROM [Messages].[Messages] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[User1] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[User2] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Date] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=1,@p__linq__1=2
```

So there is no paging in sql server and I think there is no advantage of paging like this. Does I miss something that doesn't make it work ? or it is work as this ?

Comment: Why do you have `.ToList()` in there?

Comment: `.ToPagedList()` use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` but you have materialized the query first using `.ToList()`

Comment: I think this solve the problem.

Comment: I test this and it really solve my problem. Please make your comment as answer to make it true asnwer @GertArnold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PagedList` appends `Skip()` and `Take()` to your query (calculating the number of rows to skip from `PageNumber` and `PageSize`). But the query should be the original `IQueryable` for these additions to reach the query provider and affect the SQL translation. `ToList` breaks this connection.